# Get the value of <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials= />

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I want my application to skip some logic if the user had added these lines to their config file:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```

I was thinking this would do the trick

```
System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySection dps = new System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySection();
if (!dps.UseDefaultCredentials)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

but it still just returns false, despite my config value. I could be totally wrong in my thinking here... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is creating the object from fresh, not from the config file. Instead, do this:

```
var dps = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/defaultProxy")
              as System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySection;  
if (!dps.UseDefaultCredentials)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Also, you probably want to do a check to ensure `dps` is not null before blindly reading it's properties.

Comment: Ah! [*Face palm*] Perfect answer! Thanks!